# How can I programmatically refresh the wallpaper?

Tags: 12.04, desktop-background, automation

I want to be able to choose one image file as my wallpaper and then overwrite that file to change the image that's displayed on the desktop background.

Currently, the displayed wallpaper doesn't reflect changes to the selected file until I choose it again in System Settings. How can I force it to update programmatically from, say, a shell script?

---

When I choose an image to be the wallpaper it looks the image is copied to a new location and then that copy is set as the wallpaper; immediately after choosing an image its original file name is displayed:

[image: Before]

but when I close and re-open the Appearance settings screen the name has been replaced with gibberish:

[image: After]

I wonder whether disabling this behavior would help.

Answer (score 2):

The code for Wallch might give you clues:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wall-changer/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at `/usr/share/backgrounds/contest/background-1.xml` or http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-themes-standard/tree/themes/Adwaita/backgrounds/adwaita-timed.xml.in